# How to create directory using Swift code (NSFileManager)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsfilemanager, nsdocumentdirectory

I'm having some trouble with converting Objective-C code to create a directory for Swift.

Objective-C:

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
    NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/MyFolder"];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
```

Comment: Show us what you tried in Swift, and what is that it's not working.

Comment: I think it is a bit rude to ask for what OP tried in Swift, because the question is clear enough as it is for anyone who is familiar with Swift and willing to help.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

**Swift 5.0**

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
let docURL = URL(string: documentsDirectory)!
let dataPath = docURL.appendingPathComponent("MyFolder")
if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: dataPath.path) {
    do {
        try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: dataPath.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

**Swift 4.0**

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
let documentsDirectory: AnyObject = paths[0] as AnyObject
let dataPath = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("MyFolder")!
    
do {
    try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: dataPath.absoluteString, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

**Swift 3.0**

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
let documentsDirectory: AnyObject = paths[0]
let dataPath = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("MyFolder")!
        
do {
    try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: dataPath.absoluteString, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

**Swift 2.1**

You can create directory using below method:

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
let documentsDirectory: AnyObject = paths[0]
let dataPath = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("MyFolder")

do {
    try NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(dataPath, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: As of Swift 2:

do {
       try fileManager.createDirectoryAtPath(outputPath, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription);
    }

Comment: "myfolder"? Do you mean "myfile"?

Comment: @Kampai Upvoted just because you implemented error checking/reporting. Kudos!

Comment: Use **relativePath** instead of absoluteString

Comment: Just **path** instead of **absoluteString**.

Comment: let docURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsDirectory) if you want to append a file into the path. replace 'string' with 'fileURLWithPath' or you get a URL scheme error. Otherwise, nice code, thank you.

Answer (score 70):

None of @Kampai and @Crashalot's answers worked for me.

The **.absoluteString** makes a url with **file://** prefix and it cause exception while creating directory. Instead I've used **.path** method.

The fixed code for **Swift 3**

```
let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
let dataPath = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("MyFolder")

do {
    try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: dataPath.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Error creating directory: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Comment: Kudos to you, I've been trying to figure this out for a day!

Comment: Thanks, .path was the missing part for me

Comment: While creaing folder, do we neeeed to check, whether folder exists or not ?

Comment: No, It's not needed because we send withIntermediateDirectories: true. If folder created/exists it will return true anyway. You can read more here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1407884-createdirectory

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer no longer compiles as the line with `appendingPathComponent` generates an error.

Here's a Swift 3 version that compiles:

```
fileprivate func createDir(dirName: String) {
    let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let dataPath = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(dirName)

    do {
        try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: dataPath.absoluteString, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        printError("Error creating directory: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Comment: I did try this on an iPhone but i could not find the created folder in the device. Have updated the device to iOS 11, which has the files App.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4 :**

NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains returns an array of strings, not URLs.

appendingPathComponent to string makes app crash with the message 
-[NSPathStore2 URLByAppendingPathComponent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Here's a Swift 4 version that compiles:

```
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
    if let pathURL = URL.init(string: paths[0]) {
        let dataURL = pathURL.appendingPathComponent("MyFolder")
        do {
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: dataURL.absoluteString, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription);
        }
    }
    else {
        print("Error in getting path URL");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Simpler solution:

```
"~/Desktop/demo".expand.createDir()//Now you have a folder named demo on your desk

extension String{
    func createDir(_ path:String){
        do {
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            NSLog("Unable to create directory \(error.debugDescription)")
        }
    }
    var expand:String {return NSString(string: self).expandingTildeInPath}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4

```
// DB Directory and Path
lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: URL = {

    let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentDirectoryURL = urls[urls.count - 1] as URL
    let dbDirectoryURL = documentDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("DB")

    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: dbDirectoryURL.path) == false{
        do{
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: dbDirectoryURL, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
        }catch{
        }
    }
    return dbDirectoryURL
}()
```

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 5

```
guard let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true).first else { return }
    if let pathURL = URL.init(string: path) {
        let dataURL = pathURL.appendingPathComponent("MyFolderName")
        do {
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: dataURL.absoluteString, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription);
        }
    }
    else {
        print("Error in URL path");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Other developers, Im gonna leave this here as it may help someone like me looking for a way to figure out where the folder is being created.

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) as NSArray
let documentsDir = paths.firstObject as String
println("Path to the Documents directory\n\(documentsDir)")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(lldb) p path.absoluteString
(String) $R23 = "file:///Users/vincent/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4778E487-D1AD-41E7-9B91-18E08A400DEA/data/Containers/Data/Application/286AF87C-1134-4308-9656-DEE8F9FF046E/Documents/tide/927EBC30-EAD1-44BA-80B2-FD3D0A66E9DE"
(lldb) p path.path
(String) $R25 = "/Users/vincent/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4778E487-D1AD-41E7-9B91-18E08A400DEA/data/Containers/Data/Application/286AF87C-1134-4308-9656-DEE8F9FF046E/Documents/tide/927EBC30-EAD1-44BA-80B2-FD3D0A66E9DE"
(lldb)
```

so if you receive

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=642 "You can’t save the file “927EBC30-EAD1-44BA-80B2-FD3D0A66E9DE” because the volume is read only." UserInfo={NSFilePath=file:///Users/vincent/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4778E487-D1AD-41E7-9B91-18E08A400DEA/data/Containers/Data/Application/286AF87C-1134-4308-9656-DEE8F9FF046E/Documents/tide/927EBC30-EAD1-44BA-80B2-FD3D0A66E9DE, NSUnderlyingError=0x6000009cccf0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=30 "Read-only file system"}}
```

you need

```
path.absoluteString => path.path
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).