# how to check if file exist use swift, rewrite from objective c

Tags: ios, swift

how to rewrite this objective-c language to swift?

```
NSString *filePath = @"/Applications/MySample.app";
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
    {
        // avoid open add friend
    }
```

regards.

Comment: Check this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26931355/how-to-create-direcotry-using-swift-code/26931481#26931481

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Equivalent Swift 3 Code:**

```
let filePath = "/Applications/MySample.app"
if (FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: filePath)) {
    // avoid open add friend
}
```

**Swift 2**

```
let filePath = "/Applications/MySample.app"
if (NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(filePath))
{
    // avoid open add friend
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Some years after the question has been asked I recommend to take *rewrite* literally and use the URL related API

```
let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath:"/Applications/MySample.app")
if let _ = try? fileURL.checkResourceIsReachable()  {
   // file exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let path = "/Applications/MySample.app"
let hasFile = FileManager().fileExists(atPath: path)
if hasFile {
    // use file
}
else {
    // possibly inform user the file does not exist
}
```

Comment: I created a file manually in downlods folder.I tried to access that file with the code         ```let fileDirectory="/Downloads/Receipt Data.txt"
        if FileManager().fileExists(atPath: fileDirectory)
        {
            print("file exists")
        }
        else{
            print("file does not exist")
        }``` But  it always says "file does not exist ".I am confused How to give directory for downloads.Anyone please clarify my doubts.