# How to access data in a UIPasteboard copied by Files.app?

Tags: ios, uipasteboard, files.app

I'd like to use `Files.app` to copy a folder (e.g. from Dropbox or iCloud), then switch to my App and read the contents of this folder for further processing. I can't find a way though to get the actual data from `UIPasteboard`. Calling `loadObject` on the `NSItemProvider` gives me an `NSData` archive which I can unarchive and then get a (private) `FPItem`, which implements `<NSFileProviderItem>`, but what now? How can I actually request downloading the actual folder this item points to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used one of my precious Technical Support Incidents (TSI) to have an Apple engineer give a statement.

The outcome is that at this point of time, copy'n'paste of a folder in `Files.app` to your own app is not supported. If you want to import a folder, use a `UIDocumentPickerViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you would like to download a folder from Dropbox. You may want to consider using the Dropbox API with a `URLSession.shared.datatask(...)` using a [REST](https://grokswift.com/simple-rest-with-swift/) request. If you don't want to deal with implementation details, you could use a library like *SwiftyDropbox*. There isn't really any need to use *UIPasteboard* because your end goal is downloading a folder to your app. If you would like to save said folder to the *Files app*, you can do so after you download/process the folder.

Here are some useful links:

1. [Swifty Dropbox Overview](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/swift)
2. [Swifty Dropbox Download Example](https://github.com/dropbox/SwiftyDropbox#download-style-request)
3. [Swifty Dropbox API Docs](https://dropbox.github.io/SwiftyDropbox/api-docs/latest/)
4. [Dropbox API HTTP (RESTful Requests)](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation)

In link 2, the snippet of code below gets the directory to save the file in. One way you could get a whole folder is to (1) create a new folder in the Documents directory like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26931355/how-to-create-directory-using-swift-code-nsfilemanager) and (2) iterate through every item in the Dropbox folder and add that to the newly created folder.

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
let directoryURL = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
let destURL = directoryURL.appendingPathComponent("myTestFile")
```

To implement (1), you would need to get all the files in a folder, which you can do with this [/list_folder](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder) API endpoint. Then, to implement (2), you would iterate through all the files given, downloading them like in [link 2](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/swift).

Let me know if my answer helped, or if you need any further clarification. Thanks a bunch! :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this doesn't solve my problem at all. The very reason for me dealing with `UIPasteboard` is to _not_ integrate any 3rdparty SDKs, but rely on the file provider extensions and drag'n'drop (iPad) / `UIPasteboard` (iPhone) to handle this in a transparent and canonical way.

Comment: You don’t need to use 3rd party APIs, just use HTTP requests, as provided in my answer. But if that’s not what you want, that’s okay...